# Generic function with hard coded result within implementation where parameters are not of the generic type

Tags: rust

I am trying to create an IO Data stream that is agnostic to the source or destination of the stream.  So `STDIN`/`STDOUT`/`STDERR`, `FILE`, `NETWORK` connections should all boil down to a simple `BufReader`/`Writer`

Here is a code fragment of the Reader I have so far (Some details and supporting code omitted).

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum DataStreamSource {
    STDERR,
    STDOUT,
    STDIN,
    FILE(String),
    NETSERVER(String),
    NETCLIENT(String),
    None,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct InDataStream<R>
where
    R: Read,
{
    source: DataStreamSource,
    bufferstream: Option<Rc<BufReader<R>>>, // Add single thread RefCount for now
    eof: bool,
    err: bool,
}

impl<R> InDataStream<R>
where
    R: Read,
{
    pub fn new(&mut self, source: DataStreamSource) -> InDataStream<R> {
        Self::default();
        match source {
            DataStreamSource::STDIN => {
                self.bufferstream = Some(Rc::new(BufReader::new(std::io::stdin())))
            }
            DataStreamSource::FILE(name) => {
                self.bufferstream = Some(Rc::new(BufReader::new(File::open(name).unwrap())))
            }
            DataStreamSource::NETSERVER(x) => self.bufferstream = None,
            _ => panic!(
                "There should be a valid Input DataStreamSource {:?} was passed.",
                source
            ),
        };
        //… Details left out …
    }
}
```

The problem is the `new` function (and any other function like it, `default`, etc). It doesn't like me using the actual `R` values in the `match`:

```
     |             DataStreamSource::STDIN =>
 self.bufferstream=Some(Rc::new(BufReader::new(std::io::stdin()))),
     |                                                                       -------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `R`, found `Stdin`
     |                                                                       |
     |                                                                       arguments to this function are incorrect
     |
     = note: expected type parameter `R`
                        found struct `std::io::Stdin`
```

And:

```
    |             DataStreamSource::FILE(name) => self.bufferstream=Some(Rc::new(BufReader::new(File::open(name).unwrap()))),
    |                                                                            -------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `R`, found `File`
    |                                                                            |
    |                                                                            arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected type parameter `R`
                       found struct `std::fs::File`
```

I am sure I will get a similar error once I implement something around the Network as well. I thought once I added the `R: Read` requirement, it would support all values that implement `Read`, which all these do (Write in the output case). My backup plan is to use a buffer and a pile of match statements in all the functions to use the right `BufReader` based upon the enum type, but this would be difficult to support and unnecessary. What am I missing on making this function generic?

I am just hoping elsewhere in the program to use the buffered stream in the struct to manage my IO stream and not have to worry about the stream type.

EDIT:
This problem differs from [This flagged duplicate article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936826/rust-return-a-generic-struct-from-a-function-where-only-t-is-different) in that it isn't returning a generic structure, that works fine. The problem is trying to assign a generic value within the struct where it isn't a passed parameter.  For example, the ENUM passed is STDIN, and R then needs to be STDIN but it is known at compile time. The compiler complains. These are internal types that I don't know how to create a trait to fix if that is the proper approach.

Comment: You have the exact same problem though, you want to return a `InDataStream<Stdin>` in some case and a `InDataStream<File>` in another, the only way you can is by returning a trait object or enum. The Function has to always return the same type no matter how you call it. Also how is `InDataStream<R>` with a generic parameter `<R>` not generic?

Comment: Two distinct hints: a `Box<dyn Read>` implements `Read` and can be created from both `File` and `Stdin` (and any other object which implements `Read`) or you can implement `Read` for an `enum { Stdin(Stdin), File(File) }`